# Cで文字列の配列を逆順に出力するコードを書いたのですが、最初(逆順では最後)の文字列が出力されません

Tags: c

[AtCoder Beginners Contest (ABC) 284-A](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc284/tasks/abc284_a)を解くための問題をCで書きました。
問題は「一行ごとに文字列が与えられるので、その文字列を逆順に(`n` 番目の行のものから1番目の行のものまで)出力せよ。」というものです。
下記のコードを書いたのですが、`i=n-1` から `i=0` まで `i` をデクリメントしながらループを回しているのに、`i=0` のときに出力されるはずの文字列が出力されません。

例えば以下の入力では、出力結果が期待とは異なります。
(Paiza.ioとAtCoderのコードテストで同じ結果になりました)

**入力例:**

```
4
2023
Year
New
Happy
```

**出力結果:**

```
Happy
New
Year
```

コードは下記の通りです。

```
int readint(char *s);
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 4
#define N2 111
#define N3 12
int main(void){
    char* s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
    if(s==NULL){
        printf("memory allocation to s failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(s,N,stdin);
    int n=readint(s);
    free(s);
    char* s2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N2);
    if(s2==NULL){
        printf("memory allocation to s2 failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(s2,N2,stdin);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        char* s3=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N3);
        if(s3==NULL){
            printf("memory allocation to s3(%d) failed\n",i);
            exit(1);
        }
        fgets(s3,N3,stdin);
        int j=0;
        while(*(s3+j)!=0){
            *(s2+11*i+j)=*(s3+j);j++;
        }
        *(s2+11*i+j)=0;
    }
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%s",(s2+11*i));
    }
    return 0;
}
int readint(char *s){
    int i=0,ret=0;
    while(*(s+i)>=48 && *(s+i)<=57){
        ret*=10;
        ret+=*(s+i)-48;
        i+=1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の行を削除してください。ここで1行読んだ後で、さらに後続のループでn行読み込もうとするので、合計で(n+1)行読み込もうとしています。

```c
fgets(s2,N2,stdin);
```

`fgets`はエラーの場合に`NULL`を返すので、きちんとエラーチェックをしてください。エラーチェックしていれば、(n+1)行目を読み込もうとしたときにエラーとなり、問題に気付けたはずです。

---

もう一点不具合があったので追記しておきます。
以下の入力に対し、

```
2
1234567890
abc
```

以下の出力となります。

```
abc
1234567890
abc
```